# Custom URL scheme/visibility for iOS and non iOS Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, url, hyperlink

I want to make an email signature with some links of my social networks, and when a iOS user has the app installed (e.g. Facebook) it should open there and not in a Browser.

**For example:**

If iOS & App installed: "fb://profile/user", else: "http://facebook.com/user"

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: have look at this [link](http://skookum.com/blog/open-an-ios-app-from-an-email/).. from whatever i can understand you need this funcationality

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you would need conditional content in your email and the email client of your user would need to understand it. ... which does not exist.

However, instead of the links to your social networks, place a link to your own site (e.g. http://yourVeryOwnDomain.com/social). At this page you can display the individual links to your social networks, and - because now you can detect the kind of accessing browser - you can adjust the links to your needs ...